# Add button to bottom of linear layout programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a bunch of buttons displayed using the default gravity. The last button I add to the LinearLayout view is what I'd like to appear at the bottom of the view. How do I add it programmtically to appear at the bottom of the screen? I've tried setting the gravity, but everything falls to the bottom. I just want the one button to fall to the bottom of the screen. Ideally, I won't have to make another view.

Comment: in this case, you should use a RelativeLayout , and then you put your Button at the Bottom of your Layout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the rest of the screen is not empty, you can give `android:layout_weight=0.0` to the Button, and 1.0 to the widget on the top.

In that way, widget with 1.0 weight will expand to fill empty areas, and Button with 0.0 will take only the default space, and being the last item addes to a vertical LinearLayout, it will be sticked to the bottom.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
Button button = new Button(this);
youLinearLayout.addView(button, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.BOTTOM));
```

**edit**
sorry, the code above dont work.

You cant do this using an single LinearLayout if orientation==vertical.

You'll need create another layout(RelativeLayout) and add TextView to it.

```
RelativeLayout relative = new RelativeLayout(this); 
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

relativeLayout.addView(textView, params);

linearLayout.addView(relativeLayout, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: it will not be added to the bottom man , it depens on the case, when he will launch his app on different resolutions , the result will be different

Comment: this works fine. however, there is a typo: ALIGN_WITH_PARENT_BOTTOM should be ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM